Expanding the hitting times using conditional probabilities
In the book of Markov Chains by J. R. Norris, at page 13, it has been stated that

And then asked

Then stated that

I understand the intuitive explanation why $k_2 = 1 + 0.5 (k_1 + k_3)$, but I can't figure out from where 1 comes out in the derivation, see my work below.
$$
\begin{align}
k^A_2 = E_2(H^A) & = E(H^A | X_0 = 2) \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {n \mathbb{P} (H^A = n| X_0=2)} + \infty \mathbb{P} (H^A = \infty| X_0=2) \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {n \left[\mathbb{P} (H^A = n| X_0=2, X_1=1) \mathbb{P} (X_1 = 1| X_0=2) + \mathbb{P} (H^A = n| X_0=2, X_1=3) \mathbb{P} (X_1 = 3| X_0=2) \right]} \\
& + \infty \left[\mathbb{P} (H^A = \infty| X_0=2, X_1=1) \mathbb{P} (X_1 = 1| X_0=2) + \mathbb{P} (H^A = \infty| X_0=2, X_1=3) \mathbb{P} (X_1 = 3| X_0=2) \right] \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {n \mathbb{P} (H^A = n| X_0=2)} + \infty \mathbb{P} (H^A = \infty| X_0=2) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty {n \left[\mathbb{P} (H^A = n|X_1=1) + \mathbb{P} (H^A = n| X_1=3) \right]} + \infty \left[\mathbb{P} (H^A = \infty| X_1=1) + \mathbb{P} (H^A = \infty|X_1=3) \right]
\end{align}
$$
where $A = {1,4}$ and we used the given transition rates and the markov property to deduce the last equation.
Now observe that $\mathbb{P} (H^A = n|X_1=1) = \mathbb{P} (H^A = n-1|X_0=1)$ (I couldn't mathematically prove why this equality should hold either).,
$$
\begin{align}
& = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty {n \left[\mathbb{P} (H^A = n|X_1=1) + \mathbb{P} (H^A = n| X_1=3) \right]} + \infty \left[\mathbb{P} (H^A = \infty| X_1=1) + \mathbb{P} (H^A = \infty|X_1=3) \right] \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty {n \left[\mathbb{P} (H^A = n-1|X_0=1) + \mathbb{P} (H^A = n-1| X_0=3) \right]} + \infty \left[\mathbb{P} (H^A = \infty| X_0=1) + \mathbb{P} (H^A = \infty|X_0=3) \right] \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{m=0}^\infty {m \left[\mathbb{P} (H^A = m|X_0=1) + \mathbb{P} (H^A = m| X_0=3) \right]} + \infty \left[\mathbb{P} (H^A = \infty| X_0=1) + \mathbb{P} (H^A = \infty|X_0=3) \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} (k_1 + k_3)
\end{align}
$$
where $m = n-1$.
What am I doing wrong in this derivation?
